# Show current date in meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to display the current date. I have written the following code but it does not diplay the value of `value` variable.

```
<head>
  <title>my_first_app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello from Pakistan</h1>

  {{> hello}}
  {{> date}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="date">
  <p>The time now is {{value}}.</p>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }

  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });

  var value = new Date();
  Template.date.helpers(value);


}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: You have to provide an object to the `helpers` function... `Template.date.helpers({ value: value})` or even `Template.date.helpers({ value })` in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

template.date.helpers require an object, with methods for each returnable outcome. Exactly as you have done with the counter helper on the hello template:

```
 Template.date.helpers({
        value: function () {
        return new Date();
    }
  });
```

Comment: this will return the initial value, right? the time will not change dynamically..

Comment: It will return a new date object whenever the helper is ran. You could stringify it or use some javascript parameters to format it. This will only fire once as it is not a reactive variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show current time you can write something like below

```
Template.date.helpers({
  value: function () {
    return Session.get('currentDate');
  }
})

Template.date.onRendered(function(){
  // this will update date every second, if you want update for every minute do 60 * 1000
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    Session.set(currentDate, new Date());
  }, 1 * 1000);

})
```